# How do you make a navbar that covers the entire top-screen?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a website, and I want a navbar to cover the entire screen, like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6zyc.png
I put the following code:

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  color: #ff726f;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="#" href="#">yes</a>
  <a href="#" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Commands</a>
    <a href="#">Community Server</a>
</div>
```

i've been searching for this a lot, but still couldn't find a clear answer. could someone please help me?

Comment: before you upvote or downvote, I got a gray body bg, and I'll show you this bc when you run my snippet in overflow, it doesnt show it well https://i.imgur.com/JjAFnu5.png

Comment: by default a block level element will span the entire width. You problem is mostlikely caused by the bodies default margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nav` is spanning complete area which you can see in below snippet as the `red` background .

If you want `nav` links to span in both ends you can use `display: flex;` property with `justify-content:space-between;`

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: black;
  background-color: red;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #ff726f;
}


/* Add a color to the active/current link */

.topnav a.active {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="#" href="#">yes</a>
  <a href="#" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Commands</a>
  <a href="#">Community Server</a>
</div>
```